# How much harm can a user do with xss on a page unique to them?

Tags: php, html, security, xss

For example inside of a messages page that is unique to that user.

If outputting HTML based on a query string like

```
messages?from=someuser
```

and then further own the page there is some code like

```
<?php echo 'Messages between you and '.$_GET['from']; ?>
```

Obviously whatever the user types into the address bar after the word "from" will be output to the page.

The only real problem here that I can think of is of someone else linking the logged in user to this page with a query string that has malicious intentions towards the user.

Apart from that is there anything that the logged in user can do to cause any harm to the website as the code will only be output back to himself?

**Edit**: Just to be clear, I do not intend to use this kind of code myself without sanitizing the data first. It's just a question out of curiosity.

Comment: The value of "from" can be a piece of JavaScript that steals the user's cookie value and appends it to an asset request on a remote server. The owner of the remote server then can use that cookie to impersonate the user without logging in. This attack could be as simple as a hidden iframe on a malicious website, hoping to lure in people who are logged into your insecure site.

Comment: Thanks halfer, yes I am aware of the potential of a non-persistent attack happening via someone else linking the user to that page. But what I'm asking is if there are any potential harmful things the user himself can do on that page as nothing else is happening with the data (no database insert etc) apart from it being output back to the user himself.

Comment: Well, the user could enter a `<`, which would probably break the HTML output on the page. However, if it is not stored in a database, revisiting the page without the query string would remove the problem, so no, the user can do nothing critical to themselves.

Answer (score 2):

> Apart from that is there anything that the logged in user can do to cause any harm to the website as the code will only be output back to himself?

XSS is in general an attack against the *users* of a website rather than the servers hosting the code itself, but that doesn't mean it's not potentially an attack against the service.

If you have XSS into a single page, you have remote control over the user's full interaction with anything in the site (on the same hostname/origin), by cross-page scripting inside the same JavaScript Origin.

It's difficult to say what threat such an XSS attacker poses to your site without knowing what the site actually does. I would guess judging by the description of a messaging system, an attacker could at least write an injection that would cause the victim to automatically post messages saying “I smell” to other users. If users can post links in messages, the messages themselves could link to the XSS exploit, at which point you have a messaging worm.